# Python - Unpack lists and join into a string

Tags: python, perl

I am new to Python, but I have experience in Perl coding.

I wonder if there is an elegant way to 'join' lists into a string like following Perl example in Python.

```
my $brands = [ qw( google apple intel qualcomm ) ]; #1st List  
my $otherBrands = [ qw( nike reebok puma ) ]; #2nd List  

say join ':' , ( @{$brands} , @{$otherBrands} );  
# print "google:apple:intel:qualcomm:nike:reebok:puma"
```

I've searched this for a while, but most of the answer are using * for unpacking which is not feasible in my case.

Comment: ':'.join(['google', 'apple', 'intel', 'qualcomm', 'nike', 'reebok', 'puma'])

Comment: I am not going to hard-code these brand in my code. What I intended to do is to join all elements in 2 variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `+` to join two lists, and `join` to join them.

```
brands = ["google", "apple", "intel", "qualcomm"]
otherBrands = ["nike", "reebok", "puma"]

print ":".join(brands + otherBrands)
```

If you are looking for syntax similar to `qw` in Perl (to create a list of string literals without quotes), that does not exist in Python as far as I know.

Comment: the + operator is 'elegant' enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PeterHsu your code contains `, ( @{$` and you talk about elegance? Wat. :-P (Actually I'm serious, that line could just be `say join ':', @$brands, @$otherBrands`. Still not as nice as Python, though.)

Comment: Well.. I believe that is because I know the data structure and what exactly happened in the code (reference,dereference,array syntax, etc... ). These makes me feel more...safe on the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following

```
list1 = ['google', 'apple', 'intel', 'qualcomm']
list2 = ['nike', 'reebok', 'puma']
your_string = ":".join(list1+list2)
```

The output should be

```
'google:apple:intel:qualcomm:nike:reebok:puma'
```